# How to set Image Height to Automatic inside Blocks of App Inventor 2

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am programming with app inventor.  The height value of my image in the "Designer" is 100 pixel.

Inside the "Blocks", I have a condition that need to change the image height from 100 pixel to Automatic. Is this possible?  If possible, how am I going to do that inside the "Blocks".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you also can set it in the blocks editor, just use the value `-1`
and for *fill parent* you can use `-2`

Comment: Well explain Taifun.  Thank you very much.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)